# Removal of old .AndroidStiudioX.X version folders

Tags: android-studio, resources

After updating AndroidStudio to version 1.4, I noticed there are multiple older version files, in this case for 1.2, 1.3 totaling 1.9 GB space:

[image]

Given I am using version 1.4, can I simply delete these old folders without hurting the present version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can safely delete all the previous folders. As all the caches and libraries are now transferred to `.AndroidStudio1.4`.